# Code worked in coursera sandbox editor but fails in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am super new to Python. I've been taking a Python Course on Coursera and fooling around with a little bit of code. Prior to today I was doing the class on a chromebook, and therefore using the sandbox tool provided. I've purchased an actual PC to download python since. I wrote a little code that was working just fine in the sandbox tool, but when I enter it into python it keeps booting me out. Can anyone spot anything obviously wrong with my code that I should change?

It should take an input of a date, exercise, and then keep looping through asking you about your sets and reps, saving results as tuples in a dictionary, until you enter 0, where it exits the loop, and prints the results. Stumped!

```
dt = input("Date:")
ex = input("Exercise:")
d = dict()
set = 0
while True:
    wrk = input("Insert as Reps x Weight: ")
    if wrk == "0":
        break
    set = set + 1
    d[set] = wrk
   
print(dt)
print(ex)
print(d)
```

Comment: Please define “booting me out”.  What *exactly* are you experiencing?

Comment: The indentation of the `while` statement is wrong. It needs to be at the same level as `set = 0`.

Comment: Feel using `set` is quite suspicious and not good.

Comment: Also, don't use `set` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in class.

Answer (score 1):

**Indentation** is really important in Python since it uses whitespace to differentiate between blocks of code.

Here,

1. observe the indentation of the `while` statement. Note that the indentation in the `if` block remains the same. This is because we want `break` to execute only if `wrk` is 0.
2. On the other hand, we keep `set+1` outside because the condition did not match and we wanted our program to keep running.

```
python
dt = input("Date:")
ex = input("Exercise:")
d = dict()
set = 0
while True:
    wrk = input("Insert as Reps x Weight: ")
    if wrk == "0":
        break
    set = set + 1
    d[set] = wrk
   
print(dt)
print(ex)
print(d)
```

This works as expected.

Comment: yeah, very important. once I had spent hours debugging my code and the reason was a single indent. 

Comment: My apologies, that was a formatting when adding the code into stack overflow - my code in python did have the proper indendation. Question for you - if you run the code, does python close at the end? When I hit 0 it exits out completely

Comment: @PeterFonteneau That is what is supposed to happen. Are you just double clicking the file to run it? If so it closes because the file stopped executing. To see the output use the command line or run it in IDLE.

Comment: @Ameya did IDE or linter not mark the error?

Comment: Ok thats great to know - how do I use IDLE? do I type something into the command prompt?

Comment: @NaitikMundra that time I didn't know these things, but I do. I was just sharing a fun fact about my beginning. 

Comment: @PeterFonteneau What OS are you using? Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: I am using windows 11. All super new to this ....

Comment: Okay. First, open the command prompt.(Search for `cmd` in the search menu.) This will open  a terminal window. Now navigate to the directory where the file is located using `cd`. Then run `python <nameofyourfile.py>` If this is too complicated for you, installing python would have also installed an app called IDLE. Open Idle. Then using the file menu, open your file. Press F5 to run the program. You should see the expected result.

Comment: DUDE!! This did it - you are a hero!!! thank you so much